# Type guard doesn't apply to optional object properties

Tags: typescript

I expect the `nPagination` should be narrowed down to type `{current: number, pageSize: number}` in the type guard `if` statement block.

```
interface PaginationConfig {
    current?: number;
    pageSize?: number;
}
// Throw error
const onPageChange = (nPagination: PaginationConfig) => {
    if (typeof nPagination.current !== 'undefined' && typeof nPagination.pageSize !== 'undefined') {
        setPagination(nPagination);
    }
};

// Works fine
const onPageChangeWorksVersion = ({ current, pageSize }: PaginationConfig) => {
    if (typeof current !== 'undefined' && typeof pageSize !== 'undefined') {
        setPagination({ current, pageSize });
    }
};

function setPagination(pagination: { current: number, pageSize: number }) {

}
```

But, got an TSC error:

```
Argument of type 'PaginationConfig' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ current: number; pageSize: number; }'.
  Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
```

From the code, it should be no problem, why does TS's Type Guard have this behavior? Does it make sense?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwOajmYB7EAYQJmA2QG8AoZW5BAVyignAH4AuZEBgWwCNoAbhp0ADpggBlYAC8Inbn0FQRAXyoICAZzDIC6DBEIALOCCPIAvMgAUIQ9lwEujkDnxESZAJTWAfJSitMAwdmAAnmIQeGEOmE6eAHSMzKx6AIRWNgDkDCAAJhCkIBAFOcgAZJXIkdGx3G4eBEkSRjLyyFm5+UUlZTl+1HQjyNoQYE3OIPZTnj4iIxpqIpo6egaSpuZGAOp4UADW2gBq0Nqe1nYU9Ews4AA0yG3Scihqrgnu08QgpBh+KyBYZ0ULhKIxMKpe6ZbLIPKFYqgAZVGp1SHPSQdFDdeG9JGlcpDYKjcaTL7NGY3aHpJ4vbHINQLEnLVYwfIIaZjCZzAi2NqJFyUW5pcBcHgCaB0rFvcXKaCM4lUNRAA)

Comment: You're not narrowing `nPagination`. You're narrowing its props. This prop narrowing does not propagate back to the object that contains the props.

Comment: As an aside, a quicker test for `undefined`/`null` is just `if(x != null)`. It works.